# How is the notation for constants with bitwise operator in symfony2 xml configuration

Tags: symfony

How is the notation for constants and bitwise operators like:

```
SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP
```

with symfony2 xml configuration.

I tried:

```
 <argument key="compression" type="constant">SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP</argument>
```

but got:

```
Warning: constant(): Couldn't find constant SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP
```

**Update:**
I also tried this:

```
<argument key="compression">
    <argument type="constant">SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT</argument>|<argument type="constant">SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP</argument>
</argument>
```

This does not throw an error but doesnt seem to assign the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:
There is currently no notation for a construct like this.

To circumvent this, i had to extend the PHP SoapClient to provide a default set for the options.

Alternativly you could use a Factory to create the SoapClient, also with a default options array.

Answer (score 0):

As @ivoba stated there is no native expression handling of bitwise operators for the symfony parameters.xml services.xml files or their yml equivalents.

For others looking for a method to handle special parameters, one method is that you can use a `CompilerPassInterface` to process the parameter values for you, then add the CompilerPass to your Bundle's build method, this way your container will build and cache the SoapClient.

Below demonstrates adding the SoapClient as an extension, allowing you to use it from a specific Bundle that can be included in other Applications. 
Alternatively `services.xml` can be ported to the global `/app/config/services.xml` file and the compiler can be included in a desired Bundle build method.

**Define the CompilerPass**

```
//src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/SoapServicePass.php

namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class SoapServicePass extends CompilerPassInterface
{

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if ($container->hasParameter('soap.compression')) {
            $compression = $container->getParameter('soap.compression');
            if (true === is_array($compression)) {
                //easy way to bitwise OR an array of integer values and return 0
                $compression = array_reduce($compression, function ($a, $b) {
                    return $a | $b;
                }, 0);
            }
            if (false === is_int($compression)) {
                //validation to ensure an integer value is received
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('soap.compression parameter must be an integer or an array of integer values to apply bitwise OR on');
            }
            $container->setParameter('soap.compression', $compression);
        }

        //...
    }

    //...

}
```

**Define the Extension**

```
//src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/SoapExtension.php

namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;

class SoapExtension extends Extension
{

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');
    }
}
```

**Define the Service**

```xml
<!-- src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <parameters>
        <parameter key="soap.compression" type="collection">
            <parameter type="constant">SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT</parameter>
            <parameter type="constant">SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP</parameter>
        </parameter>
        <parameter key="soap.options" type="collection">
            <parameter key="compression">%soap.compression%</parameter>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>
        <service id="soap_client" class="SoapClient">
           <argument/>
           <argument>%soap.options%</argument>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

**Include the Extension and CompilerPass in your bundle**

```
//src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php

namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\SoapServicePass;
use AppBundle\DependencyInjection\SoapExtension;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{

    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new SoapServicePass);

        //...
    }

    public function getContainerExtension()
    {
        return new SoapExtension;
    }

    //...
}
```

**Container Results:**

```
/**
 * Gets the 'soap_client' service.
 *
 * This service is shared.
 * This method always returns the same instance of the service.
 *
 * @return \SoapClient A SoapClient instance
 */
protected function getSoapClientService()
{
    return $this->services['soap_client'] = new \SoapClient('', array('compression' => 32));
}
```